# Returning null from a xbox360 XNA api method. Bad practice?

Tags: api, methods, xna-4.0, xbox360

I always considered returning a null object to be bad practice for a method call that is to be responded to. Lets say

```
Int GetFieldByID( String IDString );
```

so

```
Int m_MyReturnedID = GetFieldByID( "myGamerTag" );
```

Now, I'd assume that if the ID could not be found, we might return -1 and then handle that instead of returning a null object since that might in fact mean something went wrong internally. Anyway, I was just over on the XNA developer website and was looking at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.networksession.findgamerbyid.aspx

As you can see:

> Return Value
>
> Network gamer matching
>   the requested ID, or null if no
>   matching gamer was found.

Am I wrong in my preconception that returning a null object like this is bad practice? I suddenly have my doubts because I would assume that M$ developers should definitely know what they are doing for a service like XNA/Live etc, especially after various iterations.

Thanks

Comment: why returning -1 is better than null?

Comment: The example you're quoting doesn't match your question. The actual link says nothing about returning `int` or `null` - it says it returns `NetworkGamer`, or `null` if the specified ID isn't found. There's a difference between `int` and an Object, which is what `NetworkGamer` represents AFAICT.

Comment: @Ken White - My 1st example didn't match because it was a pseudo example which I then followed up with the XNA documentation link as a separate example. I know the difference between an Object and an intrinsic data type. Lets try answering the question.

@Maurico I don't know, hence my question. (Because it's of the same type?)

Comment: Let's try asking a question then. You might want to also work on your manners; it's very impolite to be rude and insulting to people you're asking to give you help, especially when that help is free. Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), particularly the section pertaining to how you should behave toward others. Snark and rudeness don't work here, and usually aren't tolerated; it's what helps keep this site such a useful resource. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different situations you're describing here:

- Returning a value type, which cannot be null (as in your example)
- Returning a reference type (as in the API you actually linked) - and this applies to `Nullable` types too.

A **value type** *cannot* be null, which is why you might return `-1` for a "not found" situation. You often cannot return `0` because most of the time zero is a valid value. In this case `-1` is a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Now a *variable* that refers to a **reference type** (`class`) object *can* be null (ie: not referencing any object). However you could also create your reference type such that it has a "sentinel state" that represents "not valid".

**This is, of course, a complete pain in the ass. Don't do it.**

Instead of checking this:

```
if(foo != null) ...
```

You'd be doing this:

```
if(foo != null && foo.IsValid) ...
```

Which is more work, and even if something enforced non-null-ness, you'd still have to do this:

```
if(foo.IsValid) ...
```

Which doesn't really win you anything. *Plus* you'd have to write all the extra code to handle the extra bit of state in *every single class* that you write.

The actual problem with your theory is your idea that a method should return `null` if "something went wrong internally". In that case the method should almost certianly **throw an exception**.